# differential in AHSS for spin cobordism

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, cobordism, cohomology-operations

According to [these solutions](http://www.dcrowley.net/Budapest2011Solutions.pdf), the differential $d_2: H_p(X,\Omega_1^{Spin})\rightarrow H_{p-2}(X,\Omega_2^{Spin})$ is the dual of $Sq^2$. Why?

[This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62642/third-differential-in-atiyah-hirzebruch-spectral-sequence/62644) asks a similar question (but about $d_3$ in K-theory), and the answer seems to be that there is a unique nonzero choice of stable cohomology operation. Is this also the case here? What about $d_2$ on other objects $E^2_{p,q}$? What about the differential $d_r$ on other pages?

Comment: (Re: Is this also the case here?) Sure — but one still needs to show that this operation is nonzero...

Comment: The attached notes show it is nonzero.

Comment: Let's say I want to find the action of $d_r$ on $E^r_{p,q}$ for some $p,q,r$. Am I guaranteed a unique choice? Do I simply need to find these maps on a case-by-case basis? Is there a rule of thumb, eg I can expect $d_r$ on any $E^r_{p,q}$ to be something like $Sq^r$ (maybe composed with a mod 2 reduction or Bockstein)?

Comment: Well, for any cohomology theory the first non-trivial differential in AHSS ($d_2$ for MSpin, $d_3$ for BU...) is a stable cohomological operation. All cohomological operations are known and in low degree there are very few choices. In particular, there is only one non-trivial operation of deg 2 with Z/2-coefficients, $Sq^2$.

Comment: ...Higher differentials, on the other hand, are not coh. operations but higher coh. operations ([secondary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_cohomology_operation) etc) — which are much less... tractable. (That's just my ignorance, but) I don't know if there is an explicit description even for $d_5$ in AHSS for complex K-theory...

Comment: ...BTW could you please point out where exactly att. notes show that $d_2$ is non-trivial?

Comment: Thank you. On page 10, the green colored maps ($d_2$ on $E^2_{4k,1}$ and $E^2_{4k+1,1}$) are isomorphisms.

Comment: Oh, my wording was not clear perhaps: one need to show that (not $Sq^2$ but) the operation $d_2$ is non-zero — than it coincides with the only non-zero operation of corresp. deg., $Sq^2$.

Comment: I misunderstood. I do not know why $d_2$ is nonzero. This is really the heart of my original question: what is the strategy for working out $d_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is given in the Lemma at p.751 of Teichner, "On the signature of four-manifolds with universal covering spin"[MR1214960](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1214960).